# sorting a pipe separated file based on a key field

Tags: file, sorting, unix, pipe, csv

I am trying to sort following file based on 2nd field, It should sort based on only 2nd field but it considers remaining fields while sorting. I want it to maintain order from the source file.

I am using:

```
sort -t '|' -k2,2 InputFile
```

Input File:

```
1|2|3  
1|1|1a  
1|1|1v  
1|1|1b
```

Output File:

```
1|1|1a  
1|1|1b  
1|1|1v  
1|2|3
```

Required output File:

```
1|1|1a  
1|1|1v  
1|1|1b  
1|2|3
```

When I tried using `sort -s -t'|' -k2,2 InputFile` following error is thrown:

> sort: illegal option -- s

Comment: Can you output `sort  --version`?

Comment: Hi, Can you please tell how to check the version? Any command for that?

Comment: Just run the above command `sort --version` on the command line and see what it prints

Comment: Hi, it prints: sort: illegal option -- -
sort: illegal option -- v
sort: illegal option -- e
sort: illegal option -- s
Usage:   sort   [-AbcCdfimnru] [-T Directory] [-t Character] [-o File]
                [-y[Kilobytes]] [-z Recordsize] [-k Keydefinition]...
                [[+Position1][-Position2]]... [File]...
It's older version I guess. I am able to us -s on another system having cygwin terminal.

Comment: Is there any alternative for -s in older version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
sort -t ‘|’ -nk2
```